# Create a column of sum of values after grouping two columns in Power BI

Tags: sum, powerbi, dax

I am trying to sum values of third column based on  first two columns and enter in new column.

```
Day       Product  type price  total
1/1/2019  A1       T1   3      8
1/1/2019  A1       T2   5      8
1/2/2019  A2       T1   2      3
1/2/2019  A2       T2   1      3
1/1/2019  B1       T1   4      12
1/1/2019  B1       T2   7      12
1/2/2019  B2       T1   3      5
1/2/2019  B2       T2   2      5
1/3/2019  A1       T2   2      8
1/4/2019  A2       T1   9      11
1/3/2019  B1       T1   6      11
1/3/2019  B1       T2   5      11
1/4/2019  B2       T1   4      4
```

Total is sum of price regardless of type and unique as combination of date Product. [check these excel columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HpCD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally not recommended to add a column for summarized values. Summarization is supposed to be done with *measures*.

It is very easy to get the Total for each Day and Product. First you will define a measure. In the Modeling tab, click New Measure and type `Total = SUM(Sales[Price])`. I'm assuming the name of your table to be "Sales", so you need to replace it with your own table name.

Then in the report, choose an appropriate visualization and drag and drop Day, Product, and Total. The measure Total calculates the sum of Price for each Day and Product on the fly.

[image]

It is also possible to keep the Total of Day and Product in a column inside the model. However, *this is not a best practice*. Before doing this, try to find a way with measures, and only do this if you are an experienced user and you know there is some good reason to do this.

In this case, in the Modeling tab, click New Column and input this formula.

```
Total of Day and Product = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Price]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Sales, Sales[Day], Sales[Product])
)
```

[image]

Comment: I need this column here to mimic a specific format. your solution worked great, thank you very much

Comment: Great. If you find my answer helpful, I would be happy if you accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Edit Queries > Add Column > Custom Column` and use something like this:

```
= if [Product] = "A1" and [type] = "T1" then [price] * [total] else [price] * [total] * 2
```

This  calcualation is just an example how its done because you didnt provide any information what your criterias are to sum the values in the third column. But with this example you should be able to create your new column by yourself.